# Gtk.Builder.get_objects() not returning cell renderers?

Tags: gtk, gtk3, pygobject

I'm using PyGObject with GTK 3.22.25.  I've built a UI in Glade and am loading it using `Gtk.Builder`.  My UI includes a `Gtk.TreeView` with `Gtk.TreeViewColumn` children, each with a `Gtk.CellRendererText` renderer.  One of these is called '`inventory_stock_cell`'.

I can look up the cell renderers on the `Builder` object with eg. `builder.get_object('inventory_stock_cell')` but if I try to iterate over the objects in the builder with `builder.get_objects()` the cell renderers are not included in the objects returned.

Am I doing something wrong?  Is this deliberate?  A bug?

Comment: This looks unlikely to happen based on the GtkBuilder implementation -- get_objects() seems to return every item that get_object() could ever return... Can you share a test case?

Comment: As often, constructing a test case has shown where I went wrong.  The problem is that `Gtk.CellRenderer` doesn't implement `Gtk.Buildable` and so doesn't have a `get_name` function.  This was causing an exception, which I was ignoring.

Comment: On a subsequent point, if I assign a name to a cell renderer, by setting the 'ID' setting in Glade, is there any way to find out what that name is in Python?

Comment: Or am I supposed to set widget name and then use `obj.get_property('name')`?